# Optimal Value of a Cost Function as a Function of the Constraining variable

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, numerical-optimization, duality-theorems

Consider the optimization problem :

$
\textrm{min } f(\mathbf{x})  
$

$       
\textrm{subject to } \sum_i b_ix_i \leq a
$

Using duality and numerical methods (with subgradient method) i.e.

$d = \textrm{max}_\lambda \{ \textrm{inf}_x ( f(\mathbf{x}) - \lambda(\sum_i b_ix_i - a)) \}$ .

we can obtain the optimal cost.

Now I want to express $d$ as a function of $a$ to calculate the optimal cost as a function of the constraining variable. How should I know if $d = d(a)$ is convex / concave in $a$  , if $f$ is convex and $x$ is in a convex set and the problem fullfils Slater conditions and so on?
 Does anyone know where  can I find some theory about expressing the dual function as a function of the constraining variable and the properties of this function definition?

Kind regards

Comment: Is $x$ a real number or a vector?

Comment: Vector, furthermore there could generally be more constraints and variables $a_i$.

Comment: It is edited in now. Just one more tim, it is also not the exact solution that I am looking for. I want just to do some readings to see if any properties of these functions have been investigated (which I think they probably were). I tried to show that $d(ta_1 + (1-t)a_2 ) \leq td(a_1) + (t-1)d(a_2) $ but the $d$ function definition with the infimas and maximas just flies over my head,  haha :)

Comment: Ok David, I just showed, using the simple idea from the previous comment, that for $f(x) = x^2$ subject to $x \leq a$ where $x, a$ are scalars that $d(a)$ is indeed convex in $a$. Now to prove this generally for $f$, a convex function, or at least for when $f$ is a quadratic cost and  for when the scalars in the problem are vectors... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could perhaps be useful to know that you are essentially asking about properties of the value function in parametric programming, or multi-parametric programming to be completely general.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_programming

And regarding convexity, the answer is yes, see e.g.,

Convexity and Concavity Properties of the Optimal Value Function in Parametric Nonlinear Programming A. V. FIACCO 3 AND J. KYPARISIS 4

https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a138202.pdf

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm definitely not an expert, but I'll give this a shot (maybe this
should be a comment rather than a full answer). Definitely take this answer with a grain of salt.

Consider the following
function: $p(a)=\inf_{x}F(x,a)$ where $F(x,a)=\begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{when }\sum_{i}b_{i}x_{i}\leq a\\
\infty & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

The function $p$ is convex, so I think that answers 1 of your questions. For a proof, see proposition 3.3.1 page
122 Bertsekas Convex Optimization Theory (http://www.mit.edu/~dimitrib/convexduality.html).

As far as expressing the optimal value of original program in terms of $a$, consider this the following. All dual
optimal solutions are in the subdifferential of $p$. (for a proof, see Bertsekas Convex
Optimization Theory page 187-190 section 5.4.1-5.4.2). Suppose for a
moment that $p$ is differentiable. Then then the (unique) dual optimal
solution $\mu^{\star}$ equals $\nabla p(a)$. Thus the dual
optimal solution tells you how the optimal cost changes locally as a function
of $a$. I think that is your 2nd question.

If you want to know how the optimal dual value
(i.e. the value of the dual function at its optimal level) changes
with $a$, that follows using strong duality. (Sounds like you're assuming strong duality so I will too. you need don't too much else besides convexty of $f$ to guarantee it--I think you also need closedness and properness). By strong duality  the optimal dual value is equal to
the optimal cost (of the primal problem), so now you know how that changes with $a$. If $p$ is
not differentiable, I guess it's a bit more complicated since all
you know is that the dual optimal solutions are subgradients of $p$
at $a$. I think that should still give some useful information though I haven't thought about it.

Comment: Thank you Alex, the proposition 3.3.1 is what I am looking for :).

Comment: Hey Alex, if you can still see this question, can you comment on how we show that $F(x,a)$ is convex if $f(x)$ is convex? Thanks, regards :)